# Backing up a Linux VPS with RSync to Vista

Tags: backup, windows-vista, vps, rsync

I've been working to setup a Linux VPS to host a couple of Wordpress sites and eventually a Mercurial server.

I've setup one site and things have gone well. However, before I start moving other things to the VPS, I need to setup a backup solution.

My provider, Linode, suggest RSync (among a couple of other options) to do backups. I've seen a few posts on this site that suggests other backup solutions including going to the Amazon Cloud but that costs money and the VPS is all the money I want to spend on this for the time being.

So, to help solve that I want to have my backup computer be my home desktop computer.

Assuming I'm using RSync, is it possible to use my Vista based home computer to become the destination for the backup? And if it is possible, what type of command or connection would I need to configure on the vista machine?

Any insight would be helpful. It's probably obvious, but I've never used RSync.

**Update**: While I'm considering (and attempting to implement the previously given suggestions), I'm still interested in other (perhaps) non-rsync solutions. I don't want to restrict myself to that technology if there are others that might work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use rsync on windows with [CWrsync](http://www.itefix.no/i2/cwrsync), you will need to make a batch file/script/scheduled item to initiate the backup regularly.

The script would call the rsync command.  Probably something like `rsync -a ssh://user@yourserver/folder /cygdrive/c/mySiteBackup/`

You could also try [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) to sync, then backup the files on your windows machine.

Comment: I'd like to avoid Cygwin if possible...

Comment: There's also Unison (EDITED ANSWER)

Comment: Very promising. Along with DeltaCopy, I'll strongly look at Unison. The one I implement will get the 'answer' on here. Thank you for following up.

Comment: @FrankV Which one was the answer?

Answer (score 1):

[DeltaCopy](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp) is rsync implemented in a more windows-like manner.  As I recall the DeltaCopy documentation contains an example of doing what you need.  (unix->windows)

Comment: So, here is where I'm stuck with your solution. I need to use `rsync` over ssh to ensure my data is secure. `rsync` supports this, but apparently `rsync` doesn't have (or has limited) support to do this. According to this article, http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DisplayFAQ.do?fid=1, ssh from windows -> Linux works, but not vice versa. If you know of a resource that would help, I'd greatly appreciate it. That particular faq is bringing me back to cygwin...

Comment: Yes lack of a SSH server for windows is a problem.  A quick google search turned up http://mobassh.mobatek.net/en/